# Viewing app's internet activity by URL?

Tags: applications, data-monitoring

How would I go about viewing the activity of an app based on what HTTP requests it is sending and receiving?

For example, I have an app that gets me statistics for a video game I play. I want to know where this app is sending the request to in order to retrieve the data that is displayed within the app.